# Why can't I break my powershell command into multiple lines?

Tags: powershell, if-statement, for-loop, syntax

This works (all on one line):

```
PS C:\> $list.item | % { $t = $_.tags -split ","; if ($t -contains "red") { $_.name } }
```

This, however, doesn't:

```
PS C:\> $list.item | % {
>> $t = $_.tags -split ","
>> if ($t -contains "red") { $_.ne }
>> }
>>
```

No matter what I enter, I just keep getting the ">>" prompt until I hit Ctrl-C.

What's wrong?

Comment: Can't reproduce. The code you posted works just fine.

Comment: This works for me. Do you have an extension or something that affects command prompt handling?

Comment: @ justin-dunlap @ansgar-wiechers: see the acepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get powershell to execute the command, you would in fact need to press enter twice.